# How do I use the same string in 2 code blocks?

Tags: c++

just start C++ through a series of youtube tutorials, I tried to look online but I did not know what vocabulary to use to explain my problem. I was testing pointers and I made this file which basically gets a username from the user and says it again but I don't know how reuse the username in another codeblock.

```
// Testing Pointerds.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>


using namespace std;

// This program just takes someones username and says it again.
// I get the name in void intro(), but how do I use the same string in another code block function?
// If I need to use it in 'void reuse()' how do I use the same name they type in in 'void intro()'?

void start()
{
        cout << "What would you like to be called?"<<endl;
}

void usernameGet(string *a)
{

        getline(cin,*a);

}


void intro()
{
        string username;
        start();
        usernameGet(&username);
        cout << "Welcome " << username << endl; // it has the username here but I want to use it in the next code block
        cin.get();
}



void reuse()
{
        // how do I use the same name in intro in this one?
}

int main()
{

        intro();
        reuse();

}
```

Comment: Don't learn C++ from YouTube tutorials.

Comment: Use function parameters, as you did with `usernameGet()`.

Answer (score 1):

By passing the variable around, i.e. `return` it from the place where it's first initialized and pass it as an argument to the next place where it's needed. That way you avoid global state, which is nice.

Answer (score 1):

You have to pass or return the value, something like:

```
std::string intro()
{
    std::string username;
    start();
    usernameGet(&username);
    std::cout << "Welcome " << username << std::endl;
    std::cin.get();
    return username;
}

void reuse(const std::string& name)
{
    // Reuse name
}

int main()
{
    std::string username = intro();
    reuse(username);
}
```